# What is a good usecase for job-queue

Tags: node.js, nosql, redis

I want a good job-queue usecase to update the notification to all the followers (which stored in Zset with timestamp as score) without removing the followers

**ZSET followers**

```
USER1 1234567890
USER2 2345678912
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "job-queue usecase", but Redis [LISTS](http://redis.io/commands#list) make a fantastic queue, with atomic `PUSH`/`POP` operations. You could also use [PUB/SUB](http://redis.io/commands#pubsub) publish notifications to a single "queue" with one or more subscribed workers which would send off the notifications.

Getting a list of subscribers from your sorted set without removing them is the default behavior. You would have to explicitly remove them. So, a simple `ZRANGE followers 0,-1` will fetch them all. You can play with the start/stop values when using ZRANGE to effectively grab results in batches if fetching them all at once isn't realistic.